# Fatal error while compiling: "wchar.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile some C++ codes on CodeBlocks, but I see fatal error:

> wchar.h: No such file or directory

Any solutions??

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int reverseNumber(int num) {
    int reversedNum = 0;

    while (num != 0) {
        int digit = num % 10;
        reversedNum = reversedNum * 10 + digit;
        num /= 10;
    }

    return reversedNum;
}

int main() {
    int number;

    // Input the number
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;

    // Reverse the number
    int reversedNumber = reverseNumber(number);

    // Display the reversed number
    cout << "Reversed Number: " << reversedNumber << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your installation of compiler is broken. I would recommend re-installation.

Comment: Input the number as a string.  Reversing a string of digits is a lot easier than reversing a number.

Comment: [Did you search the error?] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68835280/c-error-message-fatal-error-wchar-h-no-such-file-or-directory) Seems to be an error with your installation.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Which operating system?